# Python Selenium - Loop through web tables and place each inner text in Excel

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page with a series of tables with the class "sampleTable"
I am trying to loop through each table, and place the text of each table in sequential excel cells.

The following code doesn't throw errors, the code simply never stops.

```
Tables = driver.find_elements('class name', 'sampleTable')
TableCount = len(driver.find_elements('class name', 'sampleTable'))
For table in Tables:
    For i in range(1,TableCount):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = table.text
wb.save("excel.xlsx")
```

the following code does print all of the table text, but I can't figure out how to put it into an Excel file.

```
Tables = driver.find_elements('class name', 'sampleTable')
TableCount = len(driver.find_elements('class name', 'sampleTable'))
For table in Tables:
    print(table.text)
```

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: An internal work site, so I can't give access. But I have tried this in VBA and it works, so I know it's not an issue of the elements being inaccessible. Problem is I can't use VBA long term due to attack surface reduction rules.

Comment: Your question lacks necessary debuging details, as written. Post the full page HTML then, and confirm whether that page is dynamic, or static, ie -- can you get those tables if you disable Javascript in browser?

Comment: Can you specify one of  the outputs of print(table.text) in last loop?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. This code worked for me.

```
for i in range(1,TableCount):
    ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value = Tables[i].text
```